# Why no connection error if wrong connection

Tags: sql, .net, database, connection

I am using EF and localDB to develop an app.

At a point I get no data from my queries, although my program worked without crashing.

Then I notice the localDb connection string was wrong and then I got again data from my repositories.

I am using a `.mdf` file as my "test-DB".

My question is why I get no connection error although there is no file or database with the given name?

The connection string in `app.config` is

```
<add name="T4Context" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=C:\TestDb.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```